# jQuery 3.2.1 is not compatible with an old script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this old code which is now not working with the new jQuery library. It works well with 1.7.2 but I'm using 3.2.1 now. Is there anything to change in the code so it would work with the new library?

```html
<div class="last-screem-open" id="last-screem-open" onclick="$('#last-screem-open,#last-screem-text,#last-screem-open-button').animate({left: '-=60'}, 200, 'linear');$('#last-screem-wrapped').delay(300).animate({left: '+=250'}, 200, 'linear');">
  <b class="last-screem-open-button" id="last-screem-open-button">▸</b><span id="last-screem-text">TExt</span>
</div>
```

```js
(function($) {
  $('.macro-post-poster img, .post-block-poster img').show().lazyload({
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    threshold: 200
  });

  $("img.lazy").lazyload({
    container: $("#right")
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What you need to change depends entirely on what the errors are. If the errors are in the `lazyload` library itself then you're best off finding a more up to date one which supports the latest version of jQuery. There are *lots* already. Also note that if you're going to upgrade jQuery you may as well use the latest version; 3.4.1

Comment: What error messages or warning are you getting in your console?

Comment: I believe jQuery provides upgrade guides for [various versions](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Jquery migrate](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/05/19/jquery-migrate-1-4-1-released-and-the-path-to-jquery-3-0/), add it after your *working* jquery library (1.7.x) and it will highlight what you need to change to get your code to work in version 3.x.

Just check the console for the output.